# UIAlertView is it possible to put image as Title?

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

As I said of title, is it possible to send an image to an UIAlertView to show as the title?

Other way I can do this is showing no title and sending the image as content and after the image, show the rest of the text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the [`UIAlertView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html) does not support images in the title. Also you should not attempt to insert your own [`UIImageView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/) in [`UIAlertView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html) as stated in the official documentation :

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

Just create you own view which you present, you can present it in it's now `UIWindow` to roll you own alert view.

Comment: thanks, I will go for my own custom alert viewn then